# GitHub CodesSpaces go get my own packages fails

Tags: git, go, codespaces

I am experimenting with github.com's Codespaces and I have one private GitHub repository that is the main application and one private GitHub repository both owned by the organization. I have separate versions also owned by me, I am the only member of the organization. I also have it at gitlab.com.  When I do a go get,  I receive the same error response, with each of them. I understand the GitLab one as it is truly external and private

go get gitlab.com/dhf0820/fhirongo
go: gitlab.com/dhf0820/fhirongo@v0.0.0-20220214041735-caaf41649f66: invalid version: git fetch -f origin refs/heads/*:refs/heads/* refs/tags/*:refs/tags/* in /go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/2840587b30b2dc39c3387e997f7f37b0b273b76bb344408c91136c9093b9e992: exit status 128:
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://gitlab.com/dhf0820/fhirongo.git/'

Any ideas. I am going to be traveling with my 12.9 iPad as a dev computer.  As long as there is no private external repository, it works fine.

Thanks

Comment: are you sure about the access to https://gitlab.com/dhf0820/fhirongo? it redirected me to the login page.

Comment: You most likely have to configure authentication within your Codespace so that you can access the GitLab repository. Here’s some [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/codespaces/managing-your-codespaces/managing-encrypted-secrets-for-your-codespaces) on how to manage secrets within Codespaces.